# Set Value via Custom Table Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In the following custom table cell (`StepperProgressTableViewCell`), I have hardcoded `currentSection` to **2** for testing, but when it hits `StepperProgressTableViewCell` `awakeFromNib` method, it shows **0**.

**TableViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StepperProgressCell";
    StepperProgressTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[StepperProgressTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.stepperTableCellDelegate = self;
    cell.currentSection = 2;
    return cell;
}
```

**StepperProgressTableViewCell.m**

```
@implementation StepperProgressTableViewCell
@synthesize stepperView, currentSection;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setUpViews];
   // it always shows 0
    NSLog(@"%lu", currentSection);
}

- (void)setUpViews {
    self.stepperView = [[AYStepperView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 , [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, kFormStepperViewHeight) titles:@[NSLocalizedString(@"Processing", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"Ready", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"Delivered", nil)]];
    self.stepperView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    self.stepperView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.stepperView.currentSection = currentSection
    [self addSubview:self.stepperView];
}
```

**AYStepperView.m**

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame titles:(NSArray *)titles {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (!self) {
      return nil;
    }
    // ultimate goal is to set AYStepperView's currentSection
    // the following also prints 0
    NSLog(@"%lu", _currentSection);
    return self;
 }
```

Comment: What you are doing in setUpViews?

Comment: I am adding custom `UIView`. Please see update.

Comment: @hotspring The problem is that you are printing in Awake from nib, the value is changing but when awake from nib is called the value is the original because wasn't changed yet

Comment: Place a breakpoint in both  the places to make sure your awakeFromNib function calls after your setting cell.currentSection

Comment: @ReinierMelian, then how do I know value has been assigned/updated? Is there a way to test? Because I am trying to pass this value to change text label in the `AYStepperView`.

Comment: @hotspring you can NSLog after setting the value but must work

Comment: I have done it, but it still shows 0.

Comment: @hotspring why this line in setupViews? self.currentSection = currentSection

Comment: @hotspring solved then?

Comment: No, the issue is still on live. The current posted code is exactly what I have on the xcode.

Comment: @hotspring You need add a method to change this property and in the implementation pass the value to your stepperView, let me know if you understand me, or you can call your cell.setupViews after changing the currentSection value

Comment: @ReinierMelian, could you please illustrate with a sample code?

Comment: @hotspring Try like this In your StepperProgressTableViewCell.h

static NSString *_myProperty = nil;
- (void)setMyProperty:(NSString *)myProperty;

StepperProgressTableViewCell.m

- (void)setMyProperty:(NSString *)myProperty {
    _myProperty = myProperty;
    NSLog(@"_myProperty----%@",_myProperty);

}


in your cellForRow then add this line
[cell setMyProperty:@"2"];

Comment: @hotspring you can try like this also In your StepperProgressTableViewCell.h

static NSUInteger currentSection;
- (void)setMyProperty:(NSUInteger)myProperty;

StepperProgressTableViewCell.m

- (void)setMyProperty:(NSUInteger)myProperty {
    currentSection = myProperty;
    NSLog(@"currentSection----%lu",(unsigned long)currentSection);

}


in your cellForRow then add this line
[cell setMyProperty:2];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add a method to change this property and in the implementation pass the value to your stepperView

## StepperProgressTableViewCell.h

add a method like

```
-(void)setupCurrentSection:(int)newCurrentSection;
```

## StepperProgressTableViewCell.m

```
-(void)setupCurrentSection:(int)newCurrentSection{
    self.currentSection = newCurrentSection
    self.stepperView.currentSection = newCurrentSection
}
```

in your cellForRow then add this line

```
[cell setupCurrentSection:2];
```

Hope this helps